# Links in Excel to pages with session_start() and X-Sendfile

Tags: php, excel

I have an Excel file with a link in it.  This link points to a remote page http://www.example.com/test.php whose code consists of:

```
<?php
session_start();

// Irrelevant stuff here which requires sessions
// but which can be removed without affecting whether
// the bug is triggered

header("X-Sendfile: /path/to/pdf/file.pdf");
header("Content-Type: application/pdf");
```

When this link is clicked in, e.g., LibreOffice, the PDF file opens properly.  However, when it's clicked in Excel (I've tried both 2007 and 2010), I receive the error message "Unable to open http://www.example.com/test.php. Cannot open the specified file."

If I remove the `session_start()` line, then the PDF file opens.

How can I modify my PHP code so this error isn't triggered anymore?  Or just...what's going on?  Or...help?

Comment: presumably both Libre office and Excel are on the same computer, which in turn means they both launch the same default browser ? What browser is that?

Comment: They're not on the same computer unfortunately. Combos are:
Excel 2007 --> Firefox 48 (link doesn't work)
Excel 2010 --> Chrome 51 (link doesn't work)
LibreOffice --> Chrome 52 (link works)